# select_item=tree_frame.selection()[0] IndexError: tuple index out of range error coming in python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, outofrangeexception

I am having problems

```
select_item = tree_frame.selection()[0]
```

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

I have an `employee` table, I am trying to delete a record from the table, but when I select a record for 1st time it is working fine but while I'm trying to delete another record then it is throwing an error.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime,date
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
from tkinter import *
import sys
import time
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import mysql.connector

def show_all_emp():
    delete_page()
    emp_data_frame = Frame(main_frame, width=1450, height=720, highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=1)
    emp_data_frame.place(x=1, y=30)

    # update button
    update_selected_button = Button(main_frame, text="Update Selected Row", bg="#bb44db", fg="white", width=30,font=('Times', 10, 'bold'), command=lambda: update_data(tree_frame))
    update_selected_button.place(x=50, y=1)

    # Delete button
    delete_selected_button = Button(main_frame, text="Delete Selected Row", bg="#bb44db", fg="white", width=30,  font=('Times', 10, 'bold'),command= lambda : delete_data(tree_frame))
    delete_selected_button.place(x=300, y=1)

    # searching part according to degination choose
    filter_enter = ttk.Combobox(main_frame, state="readonly", textvariable=filter_var)
    filter_enter['values'] = ('all_emp', 'Director', 'Manager', 'Employee')
    filter_enter.current(0)
    filter_enter.place(x=1220, y=4)
    filter_var.trace('w', filter_match_show)
    #__________________________________________________
    tree_frame = ttk.Treeview(emp_data_frame)
    tree_frame.place(x=1, y=1, width=1350, height=670)
    s.configure('Treeview', rowheight=40)

    # remove unwanted parameter
    tree_frame['show'] = 'headings'
    # define number of columns
    tree_frame["columns"] = ('Employee Name','user_id', 'password', 'emp. type','report to','doj','start_date','end_date','dob','email', 'Address','Action')
    # assigning the width for column

    tree_frame.column('Employee Name', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.column('user_id', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.column('password', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.column('emp. type', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.column('report to', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.column('doj', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.column('start_date', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.column('end_date', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.column('dob', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.column('email', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.column('Address', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.column('Action', anchor=tk.CENTER)

    # assigning heading name representive column

    tree_frame.heading('Employee Name', text="EMPLOYEE NAME", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.heading('user_id', text="USER_ID", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.heading('password', text="PASSWORD", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.heading('emp. type', text="EMP. TYPE", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.heading('report to', text="REPORT TO", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.heading('doj', text="DOJ", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.heading('start_date', text="START DATE", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.heading('end_date', text="END DATE", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.heading('dob', text="DOB", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.heading('email', text="EMAIL", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.heading('Address', text="ADDRESS", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    tree_frame.heading('Action', text="ACTION", anchor=tk.CENTER)

    tree_frame.tag_configure('grey', background='yellow')
    tree_frame.tag_configure('black', background='white')

    my_tag = 'yellow'  # first row
    cn = mysql.connector.connect(database="HRMS_PROJECT", user="root", password="root", host="localhost")
    cur = cn.cursor()
    q = 'SELECT * FROM  Director_table UNION SELECT * FROM manager_table UNION SELECT * FROM emp_table;'
    cur.execute(q)
    records = cur.fetchall()
    for i, (emp_name,user_id,password, emp_type,report_to, doj,start_date,end_date,dob, email,address) in enumerate(records, start=1):
        my_tag = 'grey' if my_tag == 'yellow' else 'yellow'  # condition for row color
        tree_frame.insert("", "end", values=(emp_name,user_id , password, emp_type,report_to, doj,start_date,end_date,dob, email,address ),tags=(my_tag))
    cn.close()

    # creating vertical scrollbar
    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(emp_data_frame, orient="vertical")
    vsb.configure(command=tree_frame.yview)
    tree_frame.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
    vsb.place(x=1353, y=1, height=670)

    # creating horizontal scrollbar
    hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(emp_data_frame, orient="horizontal")
    hsb.configure(command=tree_frame.xview)
    tree_frame.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
    hsb.place(x=1, y=672, width=1350)


    def delete_data(tree_frame):
        # select_item= tree_frame.selection()[0]
        # print(select_item,type(select_item))

        select_item=tree_frame.selection()[0]
        print(len(select_item),(select_item),type(select_item))
        uid=tree_frame.item(select_item)['values'][1]
        print(uid)
        tbl=''
        type_of_emp=tree_frame.item(select_item)['values'][3]
        print(type_of_emp)
        if type_of_emp == 'Employee':
            tbl='emp_table'
        elif type_of_emp == 'Manager':
            tbl='manager_table'
        elif type_of_emp =='Director':
            tbl='director_table'

        del_query=f'delete from {tbl} where user_id=%s'
        sel_data=(user_id,)
        print(sel_data)
        cn = mysql.connector.connect(database="HRMS_PROJECT", user="root", password="root", host='localhost')
        cur = cn.cursor()

        def del_data():
            ans=msg.askyesno('Delete Record',' Are you sure!!!')
            if ans == True :
                cur.execute(del_query, sel_data)
                cur.close()
                cn.commit()
                tree_frame.delete(select_item)
                msg.showinfo('Deleted', 'Employee has been Deleted Sucessfully!!!')
                cn.close()
                show_all_emp()
            elif ans== False:
                show_all_emp()
                print(select_item)
        del_data()
```

Comment: As the error says, `tree_frame.selection()` returns a empty tuple, so before accessing its content, you need to check whether the returned tuple is empty or not.

Comment: I have already checked that , In selection function I write the code

Comment: No you didn't, otherwise you will not get the exception.

Comment: in my selection function for checking  purpose i wrote the code :  
 def  delete_data(tree_frame):
        select_item= tree_frame.selection()[0]
        print(select_item)).   for print on my console at that time whenever i select different record in  multiple time it will be take Id like 1001,1008 like this

Comment: Read the error carefully.  `tree_frame.selection()[0]` will raise the exception when `tree_frame.selection()` return empty tuple because you try to access the first item in the tuple which does not exist.  You should use something like `selection = tree_frame.selection()`, `if selection: ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you try to access the first item in an empty tuple which is returned by `tree_frame.selection()` when there is no item is selected in the treeview.

You need to check whether the tuple is empty or not before proceeding:

```py
def delete_data(tree_frame):
    selection = tree_frame.selection()
    if selection:
        # there is item selected
        select_item = selection[0]
        ...
```

Comment: yes.. exactly after 1st selection when i select another record it select empty tuple () <class 'tuple'>. As for my requirement  whenever i choose any record it's need to select a tuple like this ('I006',) <class 'tuple'>. Can you please say how to achieve this?

Comment: If you have selected an item, you should not get an empty tuple.  So I don't get what you said.

Comment: What do you want to say actually? You just copy my suggested code.

Comment: def delete_data(tree_frame):
        selection=tree_frame.selection()
        if selection:
            select_item=selection[0]
            print(select_item) I try this logic as for my 1st select my tuple element comes like I005 but when i select 2nd record that time i got empty tuple that's why my if block is not working for this reason I can't proceed my delete operation again. Please say me how to achieve this ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue, I will not get empty tuple if record is selected.

Comment: def delete_data(tree_frame):
        selection=tree_frame.selection()
        print(selection)
        if selection:
            select_item=selection[0]
            print(select_item) when i select item for first time then my output is like ('I004',)
I004, but when i try second time then my output is ()
() , I did't understood why second time my selection function not pick any data. That's the problem

Comment: `print(select_item)` will not be executed if `selection` is `()` because the code inside the `if` block will not be executed.  So how can you get `() ()`? Also you should not get `()` from `print(select_item)` because `select_item` is not a tuple.

Comment: I just add else part for understanding propose like  else:
            print(selection) for 2nd time empty () tuple comes then my else part print this values

Comment: simply I just added else part:-    else:
            print(selection,type(selection)) this is my else part and when i select data for 2nd time this block is execute and  this results comes: () <class 'tuple'>

Comment: Thank you!! acw1668 for your help and patience.

Answer (score 1):

```
def delete_data(tree_frame):
    # select_item= tree_frame.selection()
    # print(select_item,type(select_item))
    selection=tree_frame.selection()
    print(selection)
    if selection:
        select_item=selection[0]
        print(select_item)
        # print(len(select_item),(select_item),type(select_item))
        uid=tree_frame.item(select_item)['values'][1]
        print(uid)
        tbl=''
        type_of_emp=tree_frame.item(select_item)['values'][3]
        print(type_of_emp)
        if type_of_emp == 'Employee':
            tbl='emp_table'
        elif type_of_emp == 'Manager':
            tbl='manager_table'
        elif type_of_emp =='Director':
            tbl='director_table'

        del_query=f'delete from {tbl} where user_id=%s'
        sel_data=(uid,)
        print(sel_data)
        cn = mysql.connector.connect(database="HRMS_PROJECT", user="root", password="root", host='localhost')
        cur = cn.cursor()

        def del_data():
            ans=msg.askyesno('Delete Record',' Are you sure!!!')
            if ans == True :
                cur.execute(del_query, sel_data)
                cur.close()
                cn.commit()
                tree_frame.delete(select_item)
                msg.showinfo('Deleted', 'Employee has been Deleted Sucessfully!!!')
                cn.close()
        del_data()
    else:
        msg.showinfo('Select Item', 'Please Select Item!!!')
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Before I did one mistake like when my confirmation message come that time I manually call my main function but it call automatically that's why it's not work second time when I select any other data.